Showing that $\mathbb P^n_A\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ is proper.
$\newcommand{Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak p}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
Ok, so I understand what we are doing in this proof up until the very end. We set $\P^n_A=\Proj A[x_0,\dots, x_n]$, and we want to show that this is proper. Since $\P^n_A\cong \P^n_\Z\times_\Z\Spec A$, it suffices to check that $\P^n_\Z\rightarrow \Spec Z$ is proper, as being proper is stable under base change. This morphism is separated, and of finite type, so we need only check that it is universally closed, let $Y$ be another $\Z$-scheme, then we want to see that $\P^n_\Z\times_\Z Y\rightarrow Y$ is closed. It suffices to check this on open affines, so we need only show that $\pi:\P^n_A\rightarrow \Spec A$ is a closed map.
Let $Z=V(I)\subset \P^n_A$, then $I=\langle g_1,g_2,\dots\rangle$ for some homogenous polynomials $g_i$. We want to determine that the condition that $\p\in \pi(Z)$ is a closed one (this is where my confusion lies I believe, but bear with me). Let $Z_\p=\Spec k_\p\times_AZ$, where $k_\p=\operatorname{Frac}(A/\p)$ is the residue field at $\p$. Then $\Z_p$ is a closed subset of $\Spec k_\p\times_A\P^n_A\cong \P^n_{k_\p}$, so $Z_\p=V(J)$, where $J=\langle [g_1],[g_2],\dots,\rangle$, and $[g_i]$ is the image of $g_i$ under the natural homomorphism $A[x_0,\dots, x_n]\rightarrow k_\p[x_0,\dots, x_n]$.
The condition that $Z_\p$ is not empty, is equivalent to $V(J)\not\subset \emptyset=V(\langle x_0,\dots, x_n\rangle)$, which is equivalent to $\langle x_0,\dots,x_n\rangle^d\not\subset \langle [g_1],\dots, [g_n]\rangle$ for all $i$. If $S=k_\p[x_0,\dots, x_n]$, then this is then equivalent to the condition that the map:
\begin{align}
\bigoplus_iS_{d-\deg(g_i)}&\rightarrow S_d\\
[f_i]&\longmapsto [f_ig_i]
\end{align}
is not surjective. This is an $k_\p$-linear map of free $A$-modules, so this equivalent to the matrix with coefficients in $k_\p$ defining this map having all $d\times d$ minors be determinant zero.
Now this where I no longer follow. Why does this somehow imply in that $\pi(Z)$ is closed? In particular, we have found that if $\pi^{-1}(\p)\cap Z$ is non empty, then there is some matrix given by the coefficients of the polynomials in $J$ such that it is not surjective. Why does this tell us that $\pi(Z)$ must be the vanishing locus of some ideal in $A$?
I know this has something to do with the fundamental theorem of elimination theory, but the proof in Vakil's text is just as mysterious to me. I suspect there might be something I am missing somewhere.

I think your question deserves an introductory paragraph with some context. Are you trying to understand theorem 10.3.5 "Projective A-schemes are proper over A" in "The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" by Ravi Vakil?

@Lieven I am trying to do what the title shows, this was proof given in a lecture last term that I am reviewing. I have noticed that the proof in lecture is very similar to the fundamental theorem of elimination theory in Vakil

Denote $A_d$ as the degree $d$ homogenous polynomials in $A[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$. The argument goes as follows: $\mathfrak{p} \in \pi(Z) \iff \bigoplus_i A_{d-\deg(g_i)} \rightarrow A_d \rightarrow S_d: (f_i) \mapsto \sum_i f_i g_i \mapsto \sum_i [f_i g_i]$ is not surjective for all $d$ (this iff is your third paragraph, and by commutative squares the map above is equal to $\bigoplus_i A_{d-\deg(g_i)} \rightarrow \bigoplus_i S_{d-\deg(g_i)} \rightarrow S_d$). As a map between free $A-$modules, $\bigoplus_i A_{d-\deg(g_i)} \rightarrow A_d$ has a matrix representation $M_d$ with entries in $A$, which becomes the matrix representation of $\bigoplus_i S_{d-\deg(g_i)} \rightarrow S_d$ after modulo $\mathfrak{p}$. So non-surjectivity $\iff$ "all determinants of all $d_0 \times d_0$ ($d_0 = \dim_{k_\mathfrak{p}} S_d$) minors of $M_d$ (which are elments in $A$) become $0$ in $k_\mathfrak{p}$ for all $d$" (this iff is just some linear algebra). Therefore, $\mathfrak{p} \in \pi(Z) \iff$ "all determinants of all $d_0 \times d_0$ minors of $M_d$
belong to $\mathfrak{p}$ for all $d$", which is a closed condition.

I do not understand your first if and only if statement. That’s where my confusion lies. Also $A$ does not have a grading…could you elaborate each step a little more ?

@Chris From what I understand, you seem to agree that $Z_{\mathfrak{p}} \ne \emptyset \iff$ the map to $S_d$ is non - surjective (i.e. the third paragraph of your post). This is exactly my first iff-statement.

Oh yes ok you are correct, I misread. What I am actually confused is why this is a closed condition, like what is the ideal of $A$ such that $\mathfrak p\in V(I)$?

@Chris The ideal $I$ is (countably) generated by the determinants of all $d_0 \times d_0$ minors of $M_d$ for all $d$ - these determinants become $0$ after modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ so must be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Oh that makes a ton of sense, thank you.
